# How to select image from gallery and put into texture?

Tags: libgdx

I am creating a game for Android using LibGDX, the task is to insert a profile photo from the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity we write the following code to get an image from the gallery:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {

private var blockImageFromGalleryResult: (Uri?) -> Unit = {}
private val selectImageFromGalleryResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { 
        uri: Uri? -> blockImageFromGalleryResult(uri)
}

fun selectImageFromGallery(block: (Uri?) -> Unit) {
    blockImageFromGalleryResult = block
    selectImageFromGalleryResult.launch("image/*")
}
```

---

On the screen where the texture will be, it is determined that when you click on the photo, the gallery will open using the method that we wrote in the main activity, this method will return the uri when choosing an image, we will convert this yuri to a bitmap and it to a texture:

```
class MenuScreen: AdvancedScreen(1280f, 727f) {

private val photoImage = Image(SpriteManager.MenuRegion.PHOTO.region)

private fun AdvancedStage.addPhoto() {
    addActor(photoImage)
    photoImage.apply {
        setBounds(LM.photo)
        toClickable().setOnClickListener {
            MainActivity().selectImageFromGallery {
                it?.let { uri ->
                    val bitmap: Bitmap = game.activity.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { data -> BitmapFactory.decodeStream(data) }
                    runGDX {
                        val tex: Texture = Texture(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
                        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.textureObjectHandle)
                        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0)
                        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
                        bitmap.recycle()

                        photoImage.drawable = TextureRegionDrawable(tex)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```